# Removing subsets in array of Sets

Tags: arrays, swift, set

Is there an efficient way to remove subsets from an array of sets

E.g. array of arrays

```
[[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]]
```

to output an array

```
[[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Are those arrays of sets or arrays of arrays? And what exactly do you want to remove?

Comment: Arrays of Arrays, but I would like to remove all subsets. E.g. [3, 7, 10] is subset of [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 10] etc. leaving only the two supersets. I would like a way other than running isSubsetOf on every item starting from the smallest set.

Comment: if you have the principal about how you need to remove them, it is possible... according to the provided information, you could get the output array if you remove every element from the original one whose index is greater than `1`.

Comment: That doesnt make sense as the order is just an example. This could be any dynamic array of sets.

Comment: Will the supersets always be non-overlapping, like they are in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is guaranteeing the source sets are sorted in descending order of size.  That way all supersets precede their subsets.

Here’s a generic function to do it.  You could adapt it to take any kind of sequence of sequence of hashable and convert them to an array of sets on the way in:

```
func removeSubsets<T: Hashable>(source: [Set<T>]) -> [Set<T>] {    
    let sets = source.sorted { $0.count > $1.count }
    var supersets: [Set<T>] = []
    for set in sets {
        if !contains(supersets, { set.isSubsetOf($0) }) {
            supersets.append(set)
        }
    }

    return supersets
}


removeSubsets([[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]])
// returns [{10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8}, {5, 6, 1}]
```

It's still cubic unfortunately since `contains` is linear and so is `isSubsetOf`.

EDIT: here's the fully generic version:

```
func removeSubsets
  <S0: SequenceType, S1: SequenceType 
   where S0.Generator.Element == S1, 
         S1.Generator.Element: Hashable>
  (source: S0) -> [Set<S1.Generator.Element>] 
{    
    let sets = map(source) { Set($0) }.sorted { $0.count > $1.count }
    var supersets: [Set<S1.Generator.Element>] = []
    for set in sets {
        if !contains(supersets, { set.isSubsetOf($0) }) {
            supersets.append(set)
        }
    }

    return supersets
}

let a: [[Int]] = [
    [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10],
    [4, 8, 9], [5, 6],
    [7, 10], [8, 9],
    [6], [9]]

removeSubsets(a) // returns [{10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8}, {5, 6, 1}]
```

EDIT2: if you want the result to be an array of the original arrays (since converting them to sets loses their ordering), you could make the following change, which takes more space but is also slightly more efficient since it only converts the supersets to sets, not the subsets:

```
func removeSubsets<T: Hashable>(source: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    // note, this is quite efficient since arrays are copy-on-write,
    // so it is only really creating a new array of pointers
    let sets = source.sorted { $0.count > $1.count }
    var supersets: [Set<T>] = []
    var result: [[T]] = []

    for set in sets {
        if !contains(supersets, { $0.isSupersetOf(set) }) {
            supersets.append(Set(set))
            result.append(set)
        }
    }

    return result
}


removeSubsets([[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]])
// returns [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6]]
```

EDIT3: if you want to keep the original order of the sets (just with the subsets removed), you could tag them with a number on the way in before sorting, then re-sort them using it and strip it off the result at the end:

```
func removeSubsets<T: Hashable>(source: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    let sets = sorted(enumerate(source)) { $0.1.count > $1.1.count }
    var supersets: [Set<T>] = []
    var result: [(Int,[T])] = []

    for (n,set) in sets {
        if !contains(supersets, { $0.isSupersetOf(set) }) {
            supersets.append(Set(set))
            result.append(n,set)
        }
    }

    return result.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }.map { $1 }
}


// note, input not sorted in order of length
removeSubsets([[1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]])
// returns [[1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Would it work if you removed the `if let fst = first(sets)`, `supersets.append(fst)`, and `dropFirst()`? I mean, the `for` loop won't be entered is `sets` is empty, and `!contains()` will return true for the first value, since supersets will be empty anyway.

Comment: @doisk yes you are right – not sure what I was thinking there, guess I hadn't drunk my coffee before writing this!  thanks, edited

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Im looking to have each set ordered as in the original array. With output like [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6]]

Comment: @Helium3 have added a third implementation that I think does what you’re looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just like with any other (non-2D/set) array you could use an array extension like this ...

```
extension Array
{
    func slice(indices:Int...) -> Array
    {
        var s = indices[0];
        var e = self.count - 1;
        if (indices.count > 1)
        {
            e = indices[1];
        }

        if (e < 0)
        {
            e += self.count;
        }

        if (s < 0)
        {
            s += self.count;
        }

        let count = (s < e ? e - s : s - e) + 1;
        let inc = s < e ? 1 : -1;
        var result = Array();

        var idx = s;
        for i in 0 ..< count
        {
            result.append(self[idx]);
            idx += inc;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let a = [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]];
let b = a.slice(0, 1);
let c = a.slice(3);
```

Comment: Thanks but that is overkill. I am after an optimal way to do it with sets, rather than iterating over each and call isSubsetOf on each set. I dont want to process these as arrays, it will be less efficient. I should have had sets to begin with rather than converting back and forth, but thats another issue

Comment: Isn't your `slice()` method more or less what `a[from ... to]` already does?

Comment: True, that's basically the same. Only difference is it allows for negative values to wrap around and/or return reversed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If your array does not contain duplicated int values, you can convert to Set to use some feature from Swift:

(Take a look at Performing Set Operations)
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Here is my code to get another Array which does not contain subsets. This method is not optimized, it works however.

```
//let arrayOfArray = [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]]

//use set instead
var setArray : [Set<Int>] = [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]]

setArray.sort({$0.count > $1.count}) //sort to have ordered array (biggest set at first)

var result = [Set<Int>]() //you will get your result in this variable.

for _aSet in setArray {
    var isSubSet = false
    for _exitSet in result {
        if _aSet.isSubsetOf(_exitSet) {
            isSubSet = true
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isSubSet) {
        result.append(_aSet)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient way I could think of:

```
let nArrays = [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]]

nArrays
  .reduce([Set<Int>]()) {
    accu, el in let setEl = Set(el)
    return contains(accu) {setEl.isSubsetOf($0)} ? accu : accu + [setEl]
  }


//[{10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8}, {5, 6, 1}]
```

Instead of checking if every array is a subset of every other array, you just check if they're a subset of the already checked arrays. Of course, that returns an array of Sets, not an array of Arrays, but you can map() over it to convert it back:

```
let nArrays = [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]]

nArrays
  .reduce([Set<Int>]()) {
    accu, el in let setEl = Set(el)
    return contains(accu) {setEl.isSubsetOf($0)} ? accu : accu + [setEl]
  }
  .map{Array($0)}


//[[10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 3, 8], [5, 6, 1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
let arrayOfArray = [[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 5, 6], [3, 7, 10], [4, 8, 9], [5, 6], [7, 10], [8, 9], [6], [9]]
let output = arrayOfArray[0...1]
```

Comment: This is not correct. In the example its possible to see the index 0 and 1 are needed, but I want to remove subsets dynamically.